# How browser determines, where to put line breaks in Block elements/Inline elements?

Tags: html, css, web

A concrete example:

I have a menu: a list, which shows daughterly lists on :hover over its elements. For such a daughterly list I didn't set any specific width or height. I don't want to set a fixed width for the daughterly list, but don't want the linebreaks to occur as long as the daughterly menu entries can fit in one line, but for some reason browser does make the linebreaks after every word.

*Most importantly*, I wonder, what's the algorithm of putting the linebreaks. Tried to read CSS2.1 specification, failed to find the answer so far. (clarification: the parental list is positioned relative, the daughterly one - absolute; no floats; parental list is displayed inline-block).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the whitespace on the li units should do what you want.

```
li{white-space:nowrap;}
```

As to how it's deciding, it is setting it to the smallest possible width. In your case Header is the widest single element so it breaks there, if there were a word longer than header it would go to the width of that word.

Comment: Thanks, Rick! Seems, I don't get the algorithm, that determines widths as a whole. 1) Does a block element take as much width, as its parent element allots? (like if you put a top-level block element in `<body></body>`, it takes all the width of the page)? 2) If the top-level block element has explicitly set width=300px and has position:relative, and its daughterly block element is positioned absolute, shouldn't the daughterly element take as much width as possible, not the smallest possible amount, as it happens? Thanks for answering, hope my question's understandable.

Comment: I don't think so, positioning absolute is like floating and takes the element out of the document flow, so technically it doesn't have a parent element any more.

Comment: Well, it seems logical, now that you said it explicitly. Thanks once more.